# Hospedar imagens para um HTML no Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Estou com uma dúvida simples, mas ainda não achei a referência exata para solucioná-la. Apenas sei que existe a possibilidade.

Quero hospedar uma imagem para um HTML no Google Drive para ser acessível pela URL. Sendo assim, meu HTML será mais ou menos assim:

```
<img src="Url_Google_Drive" alt="example">
```

> URL seria algo tipo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=Id_Sua_Imagem

Porém, ao utilizar a URL gerada no compartilhamento do google drive não funciona exatamente no carregamento do HTML.

Sei que tem um parâmetro (provavelmente 'open?' ) na URL que deve ser alterado para funcionar corretamente mas não encontrei qual parâmetro é.

Saberiam me informar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui uma solução muito simples de hospedar imagens no Google Drive para algum HTML. Uma maneira muito simples de fazer isso é:

1º - Marque sua pasta onde ficarão as imagens no Google Drive como Pública (Compartilhamento => Configurações Avançadas)
2º - Utilize o link de compartilhamento da imagem gerada (em ativar compartilhamento de link)
3º - No seu SRC do html `<img>` utilize a URL de compartilhamento gerada pelo Google Drive
4º - Na url, troque o trecho `'open?'` por `'uc?'`

Pronto. 
Simples e funcional.

Deixei a pergunta aqui para ajudar colegas...

Comment: boa tarde sabem me informar quanto tempo esse link fica no ar? estou usando uma newsletter e preciso que não saia tão cedo do ar... Alguem sabe qual tempo de duração?

Answer (score -1):

Uma imagem gerada no google drive, gera um link

```
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/id_da_imagem
```

Mas para conseguir este link é meio complicado, você precisa ir em share, e clicar em `Get shareable link` e clicar com o botão direito na imagem e copiar endereço da imagem.

ai poderá usar a imagem no src do html não sei se é viável.

Comment: para a imagem abrir no html foi preciso trocar o `Open` pelo `uc`. Aí funcionou. Obrigado pela ajuda aí.