# Colocar imagem no html que está no google drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Como colocar o endereço da imagem do google drive no src de uma img? 
a pasta está publica (para todos) e o link gerado é este: 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qsYuljopvWNlV5ckRHSDZZalU/view?usp=sharing

Tentei o que tem nessa resposta: [Hospedar imagens para um HTML no Google Drive](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/175113/hospedar-imagens-para-um-html-no-google-drive) , mas não funcionou.

Comment: tentou usar essa url: `https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/eLMEVklGAYfVE2XqNJwR7O2lpK9mPJMjvJVH8K6ygZJTOVBOJLOmHfbxIJZ8PgRt7MoBtU-iN-t_1ZI=w1366-h638`

Comment: tentei, essa url muda depois de um tempo, ou não fica mais disponivel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Descobri um modo: Se colocar o id da imagem nessa url, da certo:

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=idDaImagem

o id da imagem eu peguei do link de comaprtilhamento que ele gera:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qsYuljopvWNlV5ckRHSDZZalU/view?usp=sharing

resultado final:

https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B_qsYuljopvWNlV5ckRHSDZZalU

Answer (score 1):

Bom se imagem se alterna, pode ser algum tipo se segurança do google para proteger arquivos, ou seja se você quiser usar uma imagem do drive no seu site o google disponibiliza iframes, oque não é ideal para imagens. vou upar essa mesma foto no meu drive para exemplificar.

após o upload irei abrir com 'documentos do google'

já no documentos clico em 'arquivos' e em seguida em 'publicar na web', seleciono a opção incorporar e clico em publicar, resultado

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1or6gRFf8L9LyyqTHfTsqVKmKJGG1HfvqZMULY6oxIro/pub?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Oque não faz nenhum sentido

porém na hora de gerar o iframe me deparei com outra url no mesmo, ao ir até ela você verá a foto em forma de documento, ao clicar somente na foto para abrir em uma nova guia ele gerou uma url extensa, que pode ser imutável mas não sei ao certo...

```html
<img src="https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/6-VhBBB5rPL_zMXXcgidUmDUcfhzGvInaXJoktZE-1Lk0eDdNDkElcyqXGyr04p3NWyamDRloz_a73IjY3VDofxmY8EwjX9lwcX6EIcKZdb7NFkxu9ZW4SYqBR_6gqKgDvfZIAj6" >
```

contudo, a menos que seja regra de negócio, não recomendo usar imagens hospedadas no drive.

Comment: Essa solução funciona, mas é mais trabalhosa que a solução que eu encontrei depois, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Denada haha, oque vale é o caminho mais curto e simples.